# Cannot host Laravel 5.2 on Arvixe shared hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I am deploying my Laravel 5.2 application to production server. I bought shared hosting plan (Personal use) form Arvixe with C Panel access and PHP version 7.0.5. But I am having problems with hosting my application.

I created a sub folder under public_html and put all contents to it

[image]

Then I browsed to subdomains:

[image]

Then I created a subdomain and mapped it to public folder of my project:

[image]

Then I redirected that subdomain to public/index.php like this:

[image]

Then when I access to http://mmfashion.mmfashionnetwork.com, it is giving me this error.

[image]

How can I share my application on Arvixe shared hosting? What is wrong with my configuration? When I run it on local machine, it is working.

Comment: What version of PHP is it running? Put `phpinfo();` in a script if you aren't sure. Laravel 5 requires PHP 5.5.9, pretty sure you are running something older.

Comment: Arvixe's website says they allow you to pick from a number of PHP versions in your control panel, see if you can find that and pick something higher than 5.5.9. If that's not available, you'll have to find a better webhost for your Laravel 5 app.

Comment: Php version is 7.0.5. @jszobody

Comment: That's hard to believe. The specific error message you're hitting is widely known as a pre php 5.5.9 error, due to the `::class` syntax Laravel uses [at line 50](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/index.php#L50). Did you get that PHP version from `phpinfo()` in a browser, or possibly from command line (which is different)?

Comment: You can see my phpinfo here. http://mmfashionnetwork.com/

Comment: I get it from browser.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the third step (redirection) since the second step 'document root' had already point to the document root, which is in your case `public_html/mmfashion/public`;

So, if anybody visits the subdomain URL, the first place it will point them to is the `public_html/mmfashion/public`;

Other steps you need to look out for

1. Make sure your .env have APP_KEY generated **or run php artisan key:generate** if it's not there.
2. Make sure you are running on PHP 7^